# My supervisor accidentally forwarded some private e-mail communication to me. What to do?

Tags: etiquette, communication, science

My supervisor has wrote to another cooperating professor regarding our project and had put me in the loop (CC). But I believe he has made a mistake and had also forwarded some of their previous private important chats and communications. I am afraid if he was willing to share those information with me. Even if part of those are relevant, but one may consider this as sensitive information of these big guys. Is that my responsibility to write back to him and inform him about this? Most of times the sender will notice such a fault, at least after sending the letter, but what etiquette say about this? I cannot say "you have wrongly put me as a receiver," because he had told me "I will put you in the loop," but this was just for the last email, not for their previous communications.

Comment: How is this topic specific to academics? It seems more appropriate for the [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/), where there are [similar questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17359/how-to-reply-in-a-professional-manner-to-emails-that-i-am-the-wrong-recipient-fo)

Comment: I would just let it go and forget you ever saw the other e-mails.  Cut the e-mails that are not meant for you out of future responses and move on.  It's his mistake and he can realize it, or not.

Comment: @RichardErickson I believe this question is relevant as the e-mail content  includes information about a project in academia so it is important to know what are the etiquette in this case. Furthermore, I am not sure if I can treat my coworker and my supervisor in the same way.

Comment: @Osh - This scenario occurs in all the time, no matter what field you're in. Unless there's something specific to academia that you haven't yet shared, this isn't really on-topic here.

Comment: It is professional to let the person know that an email was misdirected, .  - and include your steps (i.e., "I've deleted the email, and will treat the information as confidential, since I assume I was not the intended recipient" and not refer to it again).  If I were a 'student' or relatively junior and it was an advisor, I would likely rather talk to advisor in person, simply so that the advisor can see I'm serious about it. Otherwise, I'd simply contact sender via email (deleting the 'private' text-matter out of the reply email) and definitely be careful not to 'reply-all'!

Comment: If it seems likely that your supervisor will accidentally send you more messages that aren't intended for you, then I think you should inform him (the wording suggested in Carol's comment looks good to me).  If, on the other hand, this seems to have been a one-time error, then I don't think you need to do anything except delete the message.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not specific to academia.

Comment: The most important advice I can give you in relation to this incident is that you should be very careful what you send your advisor, who sounds slightly ditzy, via email, since it could end up getting forwarded to someone else without your permission (or knowledge!).

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me on two occasions, one of which would have been personally and professionally embarrassing to my advisor, or worse.

I had a pretty good relationship with him, and it was very clear the content wasn't meant for me, so perhaps my situation was slightly different, but I said something to the effect of:

'Woah, looks like the horse left the barn on this one. Glad it was just to me!'

In doing this, I admit I understand the embarrassing/sensitive material, but make clear that I appreciate it was a mistake, and also give him piece of mind that *I* am a safe confidant that can keep something to himself.